# (Jira Software Server) IntelliJ won't recognize the atlassian imports

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

We are currently using Jira Software Server (version 8.7.1) and have tried running our code in the Script Console on IntelliJ. But it seems to have a problem recognizing the imported classes although we made sure to specify the correct directory for it to import them.

These are the errors we get while running the scriptrunner code in IntelliJ

[image: Jira error message]

We are at loss here and we would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Scriptrunner version: 5.7.1.1-p5 and JDK 1.8.0_241

Comment: Made the image inline